# How Kitti calibration matrix was calculated?

Tags: image-processing, calibration, kitti

I working with other dataset (no kitti), but I need to convert it in kitti dataset format. I can't understand how calibration matrices were calculated in kitti. Example:

camera 2 (P2) calibration matrix from calib.txt:

```
[718.856     0     607.1928  -386.1448]
[   0     718.856  185.2157      0    ]
[   0        0        1          0    ]
```

I know, that

```
[718.856     0     607.1928]
[   0     718.856  185.2157]
[   0        0        1    ]
```

-- are K - camera intrinsic. But what the last column mean?

I suggested, that it's an offset from 0-th camera, measured in pixels.
From [kitti sensor setup](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/setup.php), I know that Cam 2 offsets from Cam 0 for 0.06m negatively by axis X. 
[Camera](https://www.avsupply.com/ITM/29755/FL2-14S3C-C.html) pixel size is 4.65um. But

```
0.06[m] / (4.65 * 10^(-6)[m]) != 386.1448 [pixels]
```

So what does the last column mean? And how to calculate calibration matrix just like in kitti.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the file calib_cam_to_cam.txt(calib_time: 09-Jan-2012 14:00:15) provided on Kitti Website - http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_object.php?obj_benchmark=3d, the above mentioned matrix is for **Camera 01(P_rect_01)**. As mentioned in the paper *Vision meets Robotics: The KITTI Dataset by Andreas Geiger, Philip Lenz, Christoph Stiller and Raquel Urtasun*(Section IV B - camera calibration), projection matrix for i-th camera -

```
P(i)rect = [[fu 0  cx  -fu*bx],
            [0  fv  cy  0],
            [0   0   1  0]]
```

where, bx is the baseline in meters w.r.t. the reference camera 0. The sensor setup as shown on Kitti website - http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/setup.php indicates baseline between cam 3 and cam 2 is 0.54m and baseline between cam 0 and cam 2, and cam 1 and cam 3 is 0.06m.

Now, -fu*bx/fu = -386.1448/718.856 ~= -0.537165 ~= -0.54 (**B**3-2 - **B**2-0 + **B**1-3 = **B**1-0)

Comment: what is baseline?

Comment: Basically in stereo camera setup, baseline is the distance between the lenses of both the cameras. Here is the stackoverflow discussion on the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268783/what-is-the-baseline-of-a-stereo-camera

Comment: What is `fu` and `fv`? I thought both should be same, the focal length?