# How are the addtional values in KITTI Projection Matrix calculated?

Tags: kitti

This is a follow up question to the one here:
[How Kitti calibration matrix was calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918538/how-kitti-calibration-matrix-was-calculated)

Now I do understand the values in the projection matrix, but I also see that the KITTI projection matrices for P2 and P3 are as follows:

```
P2: 7.188560000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 6.071928000000e+02 4.538225000000e+01 
    0.000000000000e+00 7.188560000000e+02 1.852157000000e+02 -1.130887000000e-01 
    0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 1.000000000000e+00 3.779761000000e-03
P3: 7.188560000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 6.071928000000e+02 -3.372877000000e+02 
    0.000000000000e+00 7.188560000000e+02 1.852157000000e+02 2.369057000000e+00 
    0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 1.000000000000e+00 4.915215000000e-03

The values in P2(1,3) and P2(2,3) and P3(1,3) and P3(2,3) are 0.0 in P0 and P1. Why is that ?
```

Answer (score 0):

P0,P1,P2 and P3 are calibration matrices of the front, back,left and right cameras
Zeroes in P0 and P1 indicates either of the 2 possibilities
1.Your dataset does not have front and back camera images
2.Thers's something wrong with the calibration

Comment: That cant be because these calibration values are straight from the KITTI dataset. Does KITTI even use back cameras ? I dont think so